# Limit log data to only specific results

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Hi so i have a touchscreen that allows guests and users learn more about our company. On the Main Homepage there are three areas guests/users and browse. These pages are Travel/Home.aspx, Menu/About/aspx, and Spotlight/Home.aspx. Each page also goes further in ie Page1 would give guests/users a list of current research being conducted and they can navigate further in by choosing the specific research project. The touchscreen also keeps a log of all the areas guests/users navigate to. I'm trying to filter this log so that I know which of the three main areas people visit the most. So far I can get my script to count and group ALL the logs like this:

> ```
> Top 5 Destinations: 12 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Home.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 5 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Menu/About.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Posters/Home.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 3 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/Home.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/Nutrients.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/Nutrients/IdentificationOfNutrientSources.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/Nutrients/IdentificationOfNutrientSources/AtmosphericDeposition.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/Nutrients/IdentificationOfNutrientSources/AtmosphericDeposition/AtmosphericNutrientDeposition.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 2 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/RegionalMonitoring.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/ResearchAreas/RegionalMonitoring/BightRegionalMonitoring.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Spotlight/Home.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Staff/Home.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 3 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Travel/Home.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Travel/LosAngelesDepartures.aspx
> Top 5 Destinations: 1 http://www..org/scraper.php?link=/Travel/Traffic.aspx
> ```

But as you can see it displays ALL the logs. I want it to group all the logs under Page1, PAge2, and Page 3 and give me a total count. This is my code so far.

```
> <?php
>     
>     #### mysql connection #####
>     $db = mysql_connect("_","guest","_");
>     mysql_select_db(networkr) or die("Couldn't select the database");
>     echo "<table>";
>     $query = "SELECT count(*),uri FROM logs GROUP BY uri";
>     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
>     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
>       echo "Main Hits:  ". $row['0'] ."   ". $row['1'] ."";
>       echo "<br />";
>     }
>     echo "</table>";
>     ?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the last piece of PHP code you posted? It seems to be doing what you're requesting.

Comment: What are the three root directories you need to count against?  I see "\*\*Menu", "Travel", "\*\*Travel", "ResearchAreas", "\*\*Spotlight", "Staff", "Posters", and "/".  A problem lies in your url's not being consistent.  The added "**" characters can complicate things.

Comment: So instead of it listing ALL the logs I just want it to show me the count for Travel/Home.aspx, Spotlight/Home.aspx, and Menu/About.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to (1) sort by the count descending, and (2) limit to the top 3 (or as many as you'd like). Something like below

```
$query = "SELECT count(*),uri FROM logs GROUP BY uri ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3";
```

Comment: This would only give me the top three for all the logs. I want to first group all the logs into those three main directories then count. So there wouldnt be a need for LIMIT 3 cause it would only show three results.